# Mounted host file becomes a directory inside a docker container

Tags: docker, containers, mount

I mount a host file into a docker container, and the mounted file becomes a directory inside the container. That's how I run it:

```
$ docker run --name <containername> -it -d -v /home/core/account_config.py:/code/account_config.py  <imagename>
```

Inside the container:

```
    # ls -la
    -rw-r--r--. 4 root root     0 Nov  6 10:25 __init__.py
    drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Nov  6 10:59 account_config.py
    ....
```

The file (in the host file system) is still a perfectly ok python file.

The source code is added into `/code` during build. The corresponding line in my Dockerfile is:

```
ADD ./code /code
```

I want to be able to change the content of config file without rebuilding the image, so I want mount it later.
What went wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Weird. Looks like a bug tbh.

Comment: @AdrianMouat your comment gave me an idea to report it as a bug. While preparing a bug report, I tried to replicate it in some minimal example, and figured out what went wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't actually know it would do that if the directory doesn't exist on the host. Not sure I was much help, but I'm glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

As it happens with (almost) every weird issue, turned out that this one has a very simple solution.

The path to host file contained a typo, so the docker automatically created a directory in this path, and mounted it to the container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to modify a file on the host machine and have changes reflect within a container, you should mount the volume via `-v HOST_PATH:CONTAINER_PATH` when you `run` the container.